# How check if text contains only one upperCase character in DB2

Tags: string, db2

Is it built-in function in DB2 to check if text(varchar) contains ONLY one uppercase character or i have to iterate a whole string and check every character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [REGEXP_COUNT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061491.html)

something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( 'Steven Jones and Stephen Smith are the best players', '[A-Z]')  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1

Result:  4
```

Take care if you can have accented chars,  you may need to change the regexp pattern to consider them (don't remember the syntax, but you can find it easily on the web).

Also, look at the documentation to specify the length unit, if using a unicode string.